# Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity on Android in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Q: How can I get the name of the activity in a Xamarin.Forms application for the application to open at the right page in the app and properly process the given file(s)?

Context:
What I mean to achieve as taken out of the Android native documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

In a Xamarin.Android context it wouldn't be too hard to figure it out from that given piece of documentation, but I'm uncertain of how to approach this for a Xamarin.Forms application.

Answer (score 0):

You have add this wrap in MainActivity of Android project of Xamarin solution:

```
[Activity (Label="Awesome Demo App", MainLauncher=true, Icon="@drawable/myicon")] 
[IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionView}, Categories=new[]{Intent.CategorySampleCode, "my.custom.category"})]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
}
```

Comment: And how would you call this? I've tried it but doesn't seem to know about this activity